# Transistor Voltage Inverter

Tags: transistors, inverter

I am a newbie and was hoping someone could assist me. Given the following schematic which takes a voltage of 12v and considers it off and a voltage of 2 volts and considers it on can someone tell me what changes would need to take place regarding capacitors and resistors (if any) to account for 20v instead of 12v? Meaning that when 20v is considered off and 2v is considered on.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing needs to be done if you're OK with about 10 mA or so being drawn from the 20 V input.

There will be more current thru the LEDs, and more base current thru Q1 when the output is supposed to be off, but both should still be within the ability of those parts to handle.

The limit is what the red LED can handle.  Worst case, think of it as being connected to a 20 V supply via 2 kΩ.  Figure about 1.8 V for the LED, which leaves 18.2 V across the resistors.  (18.2 V)/(2 kΩ) = 9.1 mA.  Check the LED datasheet, but that is probably OK.  Most "small" LEDs are rated for 20 mA, but again, don't assume, check the datasheet.

Another thing to look at is power dissipation.  (10 mA)²(1 kΩ) = 100 mW, which is OK for 0805 package or larger.  If your 1 kΩ resistors are 0603 or smaller, then you need to upgrade them to a larger package that can safely handle 100 mW.

Comment: If the output is supposed to b3 20v when off, doesn't there need to be a pullup on the collector of Q2 like there is on Q1?  Obviously, this is a question re the current 12v circuit also.

Comment: @tcro: The question was about changing the input range from 0-12 V to 0-20 V.  The OP didn't mention anything about the output.  The output is a open collector, and is specified as ON, and OFF, not some voltage.  The bare transistor does ON and OFF on its own well enough.

Answer (score 4):

If you pull up the voltage through the 1K to 20V, which is what I assume you mean, then the threshold will still be at about 2V.

It is set by the Vbe of Q1 for Q1 'on', which is about 0.6V to 0.7V. So the input voltage will be Vbe * (10K+4.7K)/4.7K = 3.1*Vbe = 1.9~2.2V.

One consideration might be that the 1K resistor will see much more dissipation. So the schematic may be the same, however the 1K should be rated at 1/2W or better (it sees 400mW dissipation worst-case with the switch closed), whereas it only saw 144mW at 12V. This is because the dissipation increases with voltage squared.